# como enfocar cursor, en primer elemento

Tags: html, jquery

necesito saber como puedo enfocar el primer input de un form, si estamos usando el tabulador, depues de que este llega al ultimo unput.

es decir por ejemplo: tengo input 1, 2, 3.

si se usa la tecla tabulador saltara al siguiente elementon de forma ordenada, y lo que necesito es que al llegar al ultimo input del form, vuelva al primer input.

```
$("#id").focus();
```

Comment: Hola, en primer lugar deberías proporcionar algo más de código con lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento, igualmente, te puedo orientar un poco, para hacer lo que comentas debes manejar tu (a tu forma) la acción por defecto al pulsar el tabulador, empieza por escuchar al evento que se dispara cunado una tecla se pulsa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093958/how-to-run-javascript-on-keypress-without-an-input-field

Comment: basicamente quiero hacer esto por ejemplo tengo el cursor sobre input con id=1, entonces necesito detectar cuando el puntero este en ese campo y si estando en ese campo pulso la tecla de tabulacion entonces me ponga el cursor en otro campo.

Comment: Pues entonces lo que quieres saber es que input se encuentra `focused`, intenta con esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus